# Show jquery element within razor syntax in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to show a particular element, `$("#lblDischargeHeader").show();` using jquery from within a razor syntax block but the current code I have, razor is trying to treat as C# code.

```
@{         
    if (Model.Patient.PatientStatusType.Description == "Discharged")
    {
        $("#lblDischargeHeader").show();

        <div id="DischargePanel" class="panel panel-danger" style="clear:both;">
            <div class="panel-heading">Patient Discharged</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Date:</b></td><td>@Model.Patient.PatientDischarge.DischargeDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td><b>Reason:</b></td><td>@Model.Patient.PatientDischarge.Reason</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

I tried using the syntax: `@:$("#lblDischargeHeader").show();` but all that does is render the line as text on my page.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the client (jquery is client side - it doesn't exist yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is JavaScript code that runs on the client.

C# runs server-side. You can't embed it server-side and have it run there. You'll need to hide the element on the server-side using C# and logic in your template or client-side with JavaScript (but no C#).